# drush Destination directory already exists

Tags: drush

I am currently running Drush on windows via cygwin.

**$ drush --version**

```
drush version 5.9
```

Now when I am trying to do a $drush up; I am getting the following error :

**$ drush up**

```
Checking available update data ...                                   [ok]
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 11/21/2013 - 11:11

Update status information on all installed and enabled Drupal projects:
 Name     Install  Proposed  Status
          ed       version
          version
 Drupal   7.23     7.24      SECURITY UPDATE available
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Destination directory                                                [error]
c:/websites/www.website.com/drupal-7.24 already exists.
```

So at the moment I have now way of updating drupal via drush.
Previous updates worked fine. I have even tried the version from github, and still has the same issue.

When looking at the --debug info :
It downloads the file fine,
extracts the files to drupal-7.24 (summary just before the error)

```
  x drupal-7.24/robots.txt
  x drupal-7.24/COPYRIGHT.txt
Calling chdir(C:/websites/www.website.com) [31.37 sec,    [debug]
13.26 MB]
Destination directory                                                [error]
c:/websites/www.website.com/drupal-7.24 already
exists. [31.37 sec, 13.43 MB]
```

So I am not sure how to get around this, or if there are some other commands I can try.

[updated edit]

More info:
My Cygwin Version

```
$ uname -r
1.7.20(0.266/5/3)
```

O/S
Windows 8.1

This might be a cygwin error, as I am getting a problem with "FAST_CWD pointer."
And I am running an older version of cygwin.

Comment: This maybe it's a silly question but... the folder drupal-7.24 exists? because seems to drush are trying to place there the new drupal version and it can't because the folder already exists.

Comment: The directory gets created once drush has downloaded the latest version.

I just noticed an error with cygwin :
The specific errors are below:
      0 [main] svn 13024 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute
FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com

So that could be the problem with my current set up. As I this problem could of occurred with cygwin and Windows 8.1. As I am still running an older version of cygwin.

Comment: Solution : Re-install cygwin.

I think the real problems was my cygwin install and windows 8.1. I have now updated cygwin to the latest cygwin64 and Drush now works.

Comment: I have the same issue with Drush 7.4.0 in RHEL 6.